# Angular states are confused which controller to use

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two states on my angular app.

First :

```
.state('profile', {
        url: '/:user/:user_id',
        templateUrl: 'modules/profile/templates/profile.html',
        controller:'profileController',
        showClose : 'false',
        resolve: {
            USERNAME : function($stateParams){
                return $stateParams.user;
            },
            USERID : function($stateParams){
                return $stateParams.user_id;
            }
        }
    })
```

Second :

```
.state('sub-moments-everyday', {
        url: '/moments-everyday/:moment',
        templateUrl: 'modules/moments-everyday/templates/ME-submoments.html',
        controller:'subMomentsEverydayController',
    })
```

Whenever I typed a valid `user` and `user_id` on the `profile` state there are no problems. But whenever I type `/moments-everyday/randomstring` it seems like the `ui-router` is getting confused. It is using the `controller` and `template` for the `profile` state.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Put the `sub-moments-everyday` state first. The problem is `/:user/:user_id` will match **any** url of the format `/something/something`. More concrete states should always be defined first.

Comment: @Phil I thought so. Thanks. But what do you mean by "More concrete states"?

Comment: States with more static parts in their URLs

Comment: @Phil Great! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried checking the order in which the states are placed in the file? /:userid/:username checks for ANY URL that matches that pattern. That pattern contains two variable parameters so when you try and access /moments-everyday/:moments, it sees the /:userid/:username pattern and calls that state.

Try making sure you have your /moments-everyday/:moments pattern BEFORE the /:userid/:username pattern. UI-router starts at the top of the file and checks each pattern going down the file till it finds the first matching pattern.

Comment: I did. This helped me as well. Thanks Cameron.